# Choose file from directory

Tags: java, android, image, parse-platform

How i can choose image from gallery and them put it on parse.com ?

There i open GALLERY:

```
            @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {

            Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
            startActivityForResult(i, 1);
            i.setType("image/*");
            i.setAction(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
```

///// - here must be code tat can choose file that i must upload to parse

////

There is code that can upload image to parse.com :

I think it will be something like this

```
                    ParseObject image = new ParseObject("guestList");
                    image.put("photo", image);
                    image.saveInBackground();
```

UPD

```
public class SendGuestPhoto extends Activity {
ImageView imageView;
private static final int PICK_IMAGE = 100;
String path;


@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.send_guest_photo);
    imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.image_view);
    Button button_choose_guest_photo = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button_choose_guest_photo);

    button_choose_guest_photo.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            openGallery();
        }
    });

}

private void openGallery() {
    Intent gallery =
            new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK,
                    android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.INTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
    startActivityForResult(gallery, PICK_IMAGE);
}

@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (resultCode == RESULT_OK && requestCode == PICK_IMAGE) {
        Uri imageUri = data.getData();
        imageView.setImageURI(imageUri);


    }



}

public void SendPhoto(){
    Button button_send_guest_photo =     (Button)findViewById(R.id.button_send_guest_photo);
    button_send_guest_photo.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

        ParseObject photos = new ParseObject("guestsImages");
        photos.put("photos", ????????????????);
        photos.saveInBackground();


        }
    });
}



}
```

Comment: You may need to post what exactly you have tried about 'File open', and whether it is working or not working. Then, someone may help you. SO encourages showing research effort.

Comment: @WhirlMind ,  i don't know what i must put to Parse (in my UPD, where contain a lot of question signs). Can you help me: what i must put in this  line ?

Comment: @WhirlMind , can you help me with my question ?